# Smart contract erc20 code snippet to prevent buyer token transfers

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, tokens, smart-lock

I´m going to start a token pre-sale and I want to be able to send the tokens to the buyer but prevent the buyer to send tokens to another wallet.

I tried the following in my ERC20 smart contract but It actually prevent myself, the contract creator, to transfer tokens. I need to be able to send tokens to buyers and prevent buyers to transfer tokens till certain time in the future.

here is the test smart contract contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5783f4e4a1bec72f41f246c50ba3d06265d984a6#code

function transfer( address _to, uint _value) public {
  require( now > 1514764800 );
  /* Rest of Function */
}

Comment: You can find a full example here https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/ReleasableToken.sol

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
modifier notPaused {
    require(now > 1514764800  || msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public notPaused returns(bool) {
    //rest of function
}
```

Comment: I have not implemented any IcoDuration function so that might not work in my case. I´m using a standard and basic ERC20 token smart contract. Can you specify in this casa how can i add the IcoDuration function, here is the test contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5783f4e4a1bec72f41f246c50ba3d06265d984a6#code

Comment: Just change now > IcoDuration to now > 1514764800. IcoDuration is not a function, its just an example of a field or variable which holds the duration of your contract.

Comment: Ok, I´ll try that and let you know! thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You will also need a variable of type address called owner which will hold your address.

Comment: I tried to add this snippet code but I´m getting compile error (undeclared identifier) so I cannot deploy the contract, could you please check the contract address and tell me where exactly should I add the code you provided. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you show me the code? Have you declared owner?

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is where you declare the identifier owner

address owner;

//whith this modifier, only you can call the transfer function 
//when now <= 1514764800.

modifier notPaused{
    require(now > 1514764800 || msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

//the identifier owner is initialized once the contract is deployed and 
//set to the address of the message sender. Note that this should be in 
//the constructor of the contract, which is always the function with the
//same name as the contract.

function ERC20Token() {
    owner  = msg.sender;
    //rest of constructor
}

//by adding notPaused here, the function will only successfully execute when
//A: you the owner call the function before or after the block 1514764800 or
//B: when anyone else calls the the function after the block 1514764800

function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public notPaused returns (bool) {
    //rest of function
}
```

Comment: Well thank you but that has make it even a bit more difficult to add the correct code in the correct place. I´m really not an expert in smart contract and I try to copy and paste instructions and code snippets but this is a bit out of my league for now...

Comment: I just made the changes you want. Is there any way I can send you the contract in a private message?